# Regular expression to match img tag with specific attribute in HTML

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that should detect a complete `<IMG ... random Parameter >` block in a large document while the ". Matches newline" option is activated in the Find/Replace function.

Example:

I'm looking for the `<IMG ... >` block that contains `Goal.gif`. I'm currently using

```
(<img.+Goal.gif".+>)
```

but with this expression, it matches the entire block. My idea is to check for a following IMG-Tag as a negation, but I don't know how to design such a statement.

```
<IMG id=NoPrint border=0 hspace=0 alt="" src="Directory\Tastatur.gif" align=baseline>
<IMG id=NoPrint border=0 hspace=0 alt="" src="Directory\Tastatur.gif" align=baseline>
<IMG id=NoPrint border=0 hspace=0 alt="" src="Directory\Goal.gif" align=baseline>
```

What regex can I use to match only the img tag that includes `Goal.gif`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have ticked `. matches newline` it is the opposite of what you want, unless some of your individual `<img>` tags are split across more than one line.

Comment: Yes you are right, its because some blocks are split across many lines. My Goal ist to replace the complete img Statements in many html documents when they contain specific Images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one I tested on your sample data in Notepad++.

```
<img[^>]+goal\.gif.*?>
```

The `[^>]+` works like `.+` but will not match any expressions including `>`. This will ensure the `<img` and `goal.gif` are within the same tag.

The `gif.*?` makes the match non-greedy, so it will only reach to the first instance of `>` following `gif`.

I tested this on the case where there is a newline between the tag start and `src` attribute, and it still worked.

Comment: Thank you, this works. But can you tell me what the "\" does before the .gif tag ? Works with and without it anyway. Is it just to prevent errors cause of the dot ?

Comment: The slash escapes the regular expression interpretation of the period. That way, it only matches a period character and not a wildcard. Without escaping it, the pattern would match img tags that include `goalAgif`, `goal1gif`, etc.